# How to calculate the distance of beacon from beacon Receiver using rssi and tx_power

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon, rssi

I have RSSI and TX_Power to calculate distance of beacon,but problem is I am not getting the distance accurate.

I try following code to find distance using txpower and RSSI value.

```
import math
rssi= -61
txpower = -64    
if rssi == 0:
    print(-1)
else:
    ratio = rssi*1.0 / txpower
    if ratio < 1.0:
        ans= math.pow(ratio, 10)
        print(ans)
    else:
        ans2=(0.89976  (ratio ** 7.7095)) + 0.111
        print(ans2)
```

Using above formula I'm getting output of distance is 0.6187m but Beacon Scanner application shows 1.40m for rssi= -61 and txpower = -64.

Comment: What do you want the answer to be?  You don't say how far the receiver actually was from the transmitter.  Where did you get the constants  0.89976 and  7.7095?  Why did you pick them?

Comment: Dist = 10.0^(TxRssi - Rssi) / 20.0); TxRSSI is calibrated (1m distance) RSSI value, RSSI is current RSSI value. (That is correct for iBeacon, AltBeacon has other calibrated distance)

Answer (score 0):

You're not really able to get a good level of distance accuracy from BLE RSSI measurements.
There are far too many variables to contend with: Every devices is different, antenna  profiles are odd shapes (so relative rotation has a massive effect), there are constant and non-normally distributed power fluctuations at both ends.

[Here's](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/18/9/2820/pdf) an interesting and fairly recent paper on some attempts to mitigate these problems, but even then the accuracy isn't great, but that's relative to your desired application:
Indoor Positioning Algorithm Based on the Improved RSSI Distance Model (2018). Guoquan Li *et al.*